# Unable to paste MS-Excel column into SWT’s Text widget

Tags: java, excel, swt

I have SWT Text widget which is created with `SWT.SINGLE`  style 
e.g.

```
Text  myTextControl  = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
```

Now, when I try to copy column from MS-Excel only first of that selected column gets pasted into Text widget and not entire column.
I do understand that when I create `Text` widget with `SWT.MULTI`, I am able to paste entire excel column into the widget but it will not be in single row.

Previously, I was using Swings `JTextField` and in that case whenever I used to paste MS-Excel column (using CTRL-V) the entire excel column gets pasted as a row in `JTextField`.
I am looking for same kind of feature for SWT Text widget.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with new line character which Excel put after each cell in selected column. `Text.SINGLE` then recognize end of the line in pasted text and trim it.

This code get the paste event and replace all new line character for selected one

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class PasteModify {

    private final String lineReplaceString = ", ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        Text tfPaste = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        tfPaste.setText("paste excel column here");
        tfPaste.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                event.text = event.text.replace("\n", PasteModify.this.lineReplaceString);
            }
        });
        shell.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```